# Wrong Time.now output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

There is such row in DB (from schema):

```
 t.datetime "password_link_sent_at"
```

And callback:

```
 self.password_link_sent_at = Time.now
```

But the output is wrong:

```
Started PUT "/email_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-22 03:22:42 +0400
Processing by SignsController#email_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"10qxpSGYRAKs/SqbWyG2IstRxpIe4VoOT96hNANq9Tk=", "email_reset"=>"user_mail@mail.ru", "commit"=>"Reset Password"}
  User Load (6.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user_mail@mail.ru' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."password_reset_token" = '2kE2dtwlnsMrnCGTIGuCvQ' LIMIT 1
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "password_reset_token" = '2kE2dtwlnsMrnCGTIGuCvQ', "password_link_sent_at" = '2013-05-21 23:22:43.167461', "updated_at" = '2013-05-21 23:22:43.175461' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (5.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb (1.0ms)
```

Pay attention to request time, and to as `password_link_sent_at` itself, as to it's update time.
Which are earlier on 4 hours.

Comment: `if @user && Time.zone.now - @user.password_link_sent_at < 2.hours` instead of `@user.password_link_sent_at<2.hours.ago` seems to be working

Answer (score 2):

You're storing times in your database in UTC presumably, and this is a good thing.

The log is set to local time.

Usually times are stored as UTC and converted for display purposes. This makes your database time-zone neutral.

Comment: The core of problem is that condition `@user.password_link_sent_at<2.hours.ago` returns false even if action was minute ago, I don't know how can I fix that?

Comment: You should always be comparing UTC to UTC times, not UTC to local times. Does `2.hours.ago.utc` make an accurate comparison? If not, you may have some conversion issues that could be resolved by forcing all of Rails to be UTC. I usually add `.utc` to all times to be absolutely sure it's UTC.

Answer (score 0):

self.password_link_sent_at = Time.zone.now

have a look here for info http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this one, but changing your's application timezone setting might help:

In config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Prague'
```